# ffmpeg: combine two mono live audio stream to single stereo stream

Tags: audio, stream, ffmpeg

I have two live audio streams, they both are MONO streams.
Now I want these two streams to merge in one stream and output to single new stream.

I am merging two input streams with following command:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://myIp:1935/live/stream1 -i rtmp://myIp:1935/live/stream2 -codec:a aac -strict -2 -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge" -f flv rtmp://myIp:1935/live/myStream
```

The above command works but when I listen to new stream i.e. `myStream`, both streams are able to listen but in **separate channel**. Means **stream1** is only in **Left channel** and **stream2** is only in **Right channel**.

What I want is, both input stream stream1 and stream2 should be available to both the channels (Left & Right).

I have tried lot but can't get success and I am not good at **ffmpeg** also. So Is there anyone who can help me in this ???

Answer (score 2):

Basically you're on the right track with your approach. But you used the `amerge` filter (the same filter is named `join` in LIBAV). This filter combines individual mono streams into a single multichannel streams.

From your description, it looks rather that you want to achieve something different: you want to *mix* those two mono streams into a single mono stream. You can achieve that with the `amix`-Filter.

Comment: yes, amix filter in ffmpeg works to merge two mono to single mono stream, thanks.